# Export Expresso Store customer data

Tags: expresso-store, datagrab, export

Client just increased scope for a project a bit by requiring us to be able to export all customer data from Expresso store so that their AS400 can store it.

I know there are some options here.. Zenbu + Hokaku, AJW Export and DataGrab.. We were already going to use DataGrab to import inventory into Expresso from their AS400 mainframe, but I wasn't entirely sure if it had reasonable export functionality that is up to this task.

Can anybody weigh in on this and advise me on my options? Do I require another plugin or can I just use Datagrab?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what format you need the data to be export into (CSV, JSON, XML, etc). Even when you have decided on a format, you probably need to massage the data into specific columns which apply to your new system.

Datagrab etc work well for import/export, I don't personally have any experience with the others. In most situations I would recommend simply writing a SQL query to gather the data you need and export it to CSV. For more complicated requirements, you could also write a simple PHP script to gather the data and display it in the format required.